# How do I block packet data for background programs?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-gio, background-data, mobile-data

I have a Samsung Galaxy Gio running Android 2.3.3 Gingerbread.

How can I block packet data for background programs only? When I disable `Settings -> Wireless & networks -> Mobile networks -> Enable packet data` the default browser and Opera Mini don't work.

(I'm trying to keep down my network billing charges!)

Answer (score 1):

If your device is rooted you can use [LBE Privacy Guard](http://www.androidpit.de/de/android/market/apps/app/com.lbe.security/LBE-Privacy-Guard) to allow/deny network access based on a per-app setting (and much more). Since I couldn't find the version I use (and shown in the screenshots) on the market minutes ago I think there's a [new version of it available](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.lbe.security.lite). But I didn't get an update via Android Market on my phone.

Answer (score 1):

If your phone's rooted, use the excellent [DroidWall](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.googlecode.droidwall.free) to selectively allow / disallow apps from connecting to the internet.

Like all apps that need root, read the instructions **carefully** and of course, do make a complete backup before trying things out.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Sparx's answer:

Droidwall has been discontinued and now forked into [AFWall+](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=dev.ukanth.ufirewall&hl=en) <sup>*Play Store*</sup> and continues in the spirit of open-source for the deprecated/obsolete Droidwall [here](https://github.com/ukanth/afwall) <sup>*GitHub*</sup>.

Answer (score 1):

Android allows applications enable or disable the "use data packet" from code (refer to [this question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11244998/enable-disable-use-data-packet-from-android-code))

To prevent for enable "Use Packet Data", you can create new empty APN and select it by default:

Settings -> Wireless and network -> Mobile networks -> Access Point Names -> Left button -> New APN

Name: None, APN: None

[Tested on Samsung GT-I8150 (Android 2.3.6)]

Answer (score 0):

Whether your phone is rooted or not – if it's running Android 4.0 or newer, there's help built-in:

1. Go to *Settings → Data Usage*
2. Tick the *Limit* checkbox
3. Use the bars in the graph to define upper limits (if you don't want any global limits, use "astronomical values": I've set mine to 3 GB, which never will be triggered. But you must set a limit here for the following steps to work)
4. Scroll the list of apps below the graph to find the apps you want to restrict
5. Tap their entry, scroll to the end, tick *Restrict background data*

[image: Data Usage]
[image: Restrict Background Data]

Done. This app will only use data when it's the foreground app now, or when you're connected to WiFi (above settings are for mobile data only).